# Read operation to server /127.0.0.1:27017 failed on database mongotmplt

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, ubuntu, mongotemplate

I am working on spring + mongodb project on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. I followed [Spring Data MongoDB](https://mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-hello-world-example/) but its giving me connection error. The data is neither getting saved nor retrieve. Below are the configuration of mongodb in my ubuntu:[image]. I guess I am using newer version of mongodb which is causing conflict. Below are the configuration files: 1. SpringMongoConfig1.java, where I have created db "mongotmplt" and collection "users" which is empty currently.

```
@Configuration
public class SpringMongoConfig1 {
    public @Bean
    MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(), "mongotmplt");
    }
    public @Bean
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());  
        return mongoTemplate;   
    }
}
```

2.SpringConfig.xml

```
    <mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="mongotmplt" />

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean>
```

The error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Read operation to server /127.0.0.1:27017 failed on database mongotmplt; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Read operation to server /127.0.0.1:27017 failed on database mongotmplt
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:1665)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1495)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:475)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:470)
    at com.example.mongo2.Mongo2Application.main(Mongo2Application.java:37)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Read operation to server /127.0.0.1:27017 failed on database mongotmplt
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:253)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:216)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:288)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:273)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:728)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:670)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$FindOneCallback.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:1720)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$FindOneCallback.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:1705)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1491)
```

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 0):

There might be some configuration issue with the tutorial provided in the implementation. The proper implementation of spring data-mongotemplate is given in [javainterviewpoint](https://www.javainterviewpoint.com/spring-data-mongodb-example/)